# how to use custom validator for multiple controls?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, infragistics, asp.net-validators

I have date fields and I want to validate if both the dates are selected or none.
I have added the following customValidator

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" Text="You must select both or no dates" ClientValidationFunction="dateValidate"  ValidateEmptyText="false" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

But it does not work if I am not adding customvalidator. My client side function is below. This method works fine otherwise when I am validating in date fields directly but I am trying to implement it using customvalidator.

```
    function dateValidate(sender, args) {

        var From = document.getElementById('dataContentplaceholder_wdpFrom').title;

        var To = document.getElementById('dataContentplaceholder_wdpTo').title;
        if (From.toString.length == 0 && To.toString.length >=1 || To.toString.length == 0 && From.toString.length >=1) {

            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else {

            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your question is confusing; are you able to validate using that script in custom validator or not?

Comment: It does not validate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date fields are rendered as TextBoxes (I am not familiar with Infragistics), you could use a markup similar to this one:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" onchange="ValidateTexts();" ... />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server" onchange="ValidateTexts();" ... />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="customValidator1" runat="server" Text="You must select both or no dates" ForeColor="Red" ClientValidationFunction="txtValidate"  ValidateEmptyText="true" ... />
```

With the following client-code:

```
function ValidateTexts() {
    ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById('<%= customValidator1.ClientID %>'));
}

function txtValidate(sender, args) {
    var from = document.getElementById('<%= txtBox1.ClientID %>').value;
    var to = document.getElementById('<%= txtBox2.ClientID %>').value;
    args.IsValid = (from.length == 0 && to.length == 0) || (to.length > 0 && from.length > 0);
}
```

The `onchange` event handler is called when a modified field loses focus. Without it, the validation is done only when a postback is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Your customValidator should be fired by some submit button.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" ... />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server" ... />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cVal" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must select both or no dates" ClientValidationFunction="valDates">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValudator>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

function valDates(s, e){
    var txt1 = document.getElementById(s.id.replace('cVal', 'txtBox1'));
    var txt2 = document.getElementById(s.id.replace('cVal', 'txtBox2'));
    if(!(txt1.value && txt2.value) && !(!txt1.value && !txt2.value))
        e.IsValid = false;
}
```